# How can I change my code to accept user inputs

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I have working code that encrypts a phrase using a caesar cipher but this is with predetermined inputs (HELLOWORLD and 4 as the sift).

What I would like to do is enable a user to choose their own input and shift.

More specifically in the format:

e.g. $java Caesar 3 HELLOWORLD

and so "HELLOWORLD" is shifted 3 times

Comment: Have you tried searching the web for anything like "java get user input" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = scanner.nextLine();
int i = scanner.nextInt();
```

Ask your question then the user types the result in console.

Answer (score 0):

To use commandline arguments, just use `args[0]` `args[1]` etc.. So in your example "3 HELLOWORLD" - 3 is `args[0]` and HELLOWORLD is `args[1]`.

As `shift` is an integer you must parse it which converts it from a String to an Integer. To improve the code, you should catch any errors incase the String entered cannot be converted.

```
    public static StringBuffer rotate(int shift, String plainText){
    StringBuffer result= new StringBuffer();

    for (int i=0; i<plainText.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(plainText.charAt(i))){
            char ch = (char)(((int)plainText.charAt(i) + shift - 65) % 26 + 65);
            result.append(ch);
        }
        else{
            char ch = (char)(((int)plainText.charAt(i) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97);
            result.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return result;
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    String plainText = args[1];
    int shift = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    System.out.println("Text  : " + plainText);
    System.out.println("Shift : " + shift);
    System.out.println("Cipher: " + rotate(shift, plainText));
}
```

[This is the output after using the arguments you mentioned](https://gyazo.com/d2b7d171e4d3b604f74f990815b46ce4)